# How to use next available port in http.ListenAndServe

Tags: http, go, webserver, port

I wrote a simple web server to listen on port 8080. But I don't want to use a hard coded port number. What I want is that my server listen on any available port. And I want to know that on what port number my web server is listening.

My code is given bellow:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {       
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You may use port `0` to indicate you're not specifying an exact port but you want a free, available port selected by the system:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":0", nil)
```

The problem with this is that you won't be able to find out what port was assigned. So you need to create the [`net.Listener`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener) yourself (using the [`net.Listen()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listen) function), and manually pass it to [`http.Serve()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve):

```
listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":0")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Using port:", listener.Addr().(*net.TCPAddr).Port)

panic(http.Serve(listener, nil))
```

Example output:

```
Using port: 42039
```

As you can see, you can access the assigned port from the `net.Listener`, from its [`net.Addr`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Addr) address (acquired by its `Addr()` method). `net.Addr` does not directly give access to the port, but since we created the `net.Listener` using `tcp` network stream, the `net.Addr` will be of dynamic type [`*net.TCPAddr`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPAddr) (which we can acquire with a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)), which is a struct and has a field `Port int`.

Note that if you don't need the port in your application (e.g. you just want to display it for yourself), you don't need the type assertion, you can just print `listener.Addr()` (which will contain the port at the end):

```
fmt.Println("Address:", listener.Addr())
```

Example output:

```
Address: [::]:42039
```

Also don't forget to handle returned errors (`http.ListenAndServe()` in this case). In my example I simply passed it to `panic()` because `http.LitenAndServe()` and `http.Serve()` block if everything goes well (so they only return if there's an error, which I pass to `panic()`).

Comment: Please don't panic in production, will terminate other threads running causes issues.

Answer (score 8):

I landed on this page because I wanted to start a new server on a random port for testing purposes. I later learned about the `httptest` package, https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/ , which does a much better job of managing temporary HTTP server for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Package https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest supports HTTP server on random port.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func main() {       
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
    })

    server := httptest.NewServer(handler)
    defer server.Close()

    fmt.Println("Server started", server.URL)
}
```

Example output

```
Server started http://127.0.0.1:54926
```